# Problemas al insertar datos a una DB usando Netbeans 11.2 en mac os x

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, macos

Estor tratando de insertar datos a una DB hecha en MAMP.
Cuando trato de usar una clase que llame Insertar no logro insertar los datos, pero si uso Execute Command si lo inserta.

Mi código:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Insertar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            Connection miConexion = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/colegio","root","123456");
          // System.out.println("Conexion Exitosa!!!");

          Statement miStatement = miConexion.createStatement();
            String insertar = "insert into alumno(nombre, ciudad, telefono) values('Luis','Guatemala','9898643');";
                 miStatement.executeUpdate(insertar);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Al correr la clase me da: 
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/colegio.

Tengo estos Drivers:

[image: Drivers]

Como les repito si ejecuto la instrucción sobre la conexión si inserta datos.

[image: Datos insertados]

[image: Tabla en MAMP]

[image: Desde Netbeans 11.2]

¿Serian tan amables de hacerme ver donde estoy fallando?
Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Este es mi pom.mxl

[image: pom.mxl]

Así quedo la solución para que la vea alguien mas que tenga el mismo problema.

[image: Solución agregando dependencias]

Comment: Los drivers que has puesto son los que usa netbeans para acceder a la base de datos, pero necesitas que tu driver esté en el classpath de tu aplicación para que funcione. ¿Puedes pegar tu pom.xml? Seguramente necesites añadir una dependencia para el conector de mysql de java y añadir una sentencia Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver") o el nombre del driver que sea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41492527/mysql-driver-in-java-project

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, perdón por mi falta de conocimiento, en que carpeta encuentro el pom.xml? leeré el link que me enviaste, mil gracias.

Comment: Debería estar en la raíz del proyecto maven que has creado

Comment: Mil gracias, lo solucione con tu ayuda! hay alguna forma que Netbeans ponga las dependencias de forma automática? o siempre hay que ponerlas a mano?

Comment: Cada proyecto puede tener diferentes dependencias, y como es una cosa algo delicada, yo personalmente las pondría a mano. De todas formas en netbeans si tienes un proyecto maven y haces click derecho en dependencies puedes añadirlas desde un cuadro de diálogo y te generá el código XML necesario. A mi me gusta mas ir a https://mvnrepository.com/ y copiar y pegar la dependencia que necesito directamente en el pom.xml